# Visual Studio: replacing { and new line

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace, visual-studio-2013, find

I found out that I can write in the "find and replace box" regular expression in order to find new line inside the code of Visual Studio, but what I want to do is "for every '{' followed by a new line, replace it with the next syntax symbol". In other words:

```
class Parser5 : Parser
{
    public Parser5(Scanner scanner) : base(scanner)
    { }
    public override Loop ParseLoop()
    {
        if(//some stuff)
        {
               return this.ParseNestedLoop();
        }
    }
}
```

With:

```
class Parser5 : Parser
{   public Parser5(Scanner scanner) : base(scanner)
    { }
    public override Loop ParseLoop()
    {   if(//some stuff)
        {return this.ParseNestedLoop();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 \{\n(?<=\{\n)(.*$)
```

You can use this.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sA7pZ0/31

Comment: Yeah, it sounds pretty good, but why the new text is moved on the right? There is some way to move it more on left (in the same vertical position as before)?

Comment: \{\n(?<=\{\n)\s*(.*$) try this